# Use PHP background image and inherit CSS styling

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I'm using CSS to call a background image that populates several thumbnails (works great!) but I ave been told I need to use PHP now and one more thing I have to comply with a strict no img tag policy (only spans).

This is the workable site: www.xxlbreakcomp.com

I tired calling the image using this line of php:

```
    <span style="background: url('<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?> /library/images/thumb.pic.jpg"></span>
```

I see it in the inspector but there is a line through it (even when I delete the css reference) so I am lost. If it helps the reason we are switching to PHP is because we will eventually use a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using both single and double quotes and missing the closing parentheses.

```
url('<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/library/images/thumb_pic.png')
```

Comment: Too easy and Works perfectly. The coding gods were on my side today.Thanks